# Nexus S (Android 2.3) use Front-Facing Camera compatible with 2.2

Tags: android, android-camera, android-2.2-froyo

I'm searching a method to use front facing camera but with compatibility with Android 2.2.

I've seen than Android 2.3 bring Camera.open(Idx) but I need to use with Android 2.2 too.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this, I'm working through this as well.

```
Camera camera = Camera.open();
camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
params.set("camera-id", 2);
camera.setParameters(params);
```